# Does MMS support PNG format images?

Tags: mms

I'm just wondering if android mms supports png files? I've tried sending an image, a png format, through mms. Sending is successful. However, the recipient recieves an error image. My question is, does android mms supports sending and receiving PNG format images?

Samsung Galaxy 5

Comment: I've heard some MMS implementations will rename PNG files to .jpg while leaving the MIME type intact, which confuses/breaks some messaging apps.  Not sure if this is the case with Android however.

Comment: What was the model phone you were trying to send the .png format picture to? my friend has my old lg motion and cant accept the .png screenshots my gs3 makes and we cant figure this out either. im going to have to try a new messaging service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes MMS can send png files. Even if they change the extension, it shouldn't matter as long as the mime type is in tact. and even if that is different, the image has a specific "header" that should be read by the MMS app. AFAIK, android does not change the extension, or the mime type. (at least the stock MMS app, and the Galaxy S app)

But that doesn't mean it will work with other phones. They might not have the ability to view the file type.